# Replace \" in a string

Tags: c#

I have a problem which seems simple, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to accomplish it.

Here is my starting string:

```
Hello \"this is my string\"
```

Here is what I want the result to be:

```
Hello "this is my string"
```

So basically, I need to replace `\"` with just `"`.

I **do not** want to just remove ALL occurrences of `\` since a single backslash could exist elsewhere in my string. I just want to replace occurrences of `\"` with `"`.

Comment: Where do you see ``\`` ? in debugger ?

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: Does your string actually contain `\"` ? Because that's how the debugger shows a `"`

Comment: If really your string contains `\"` you can use `s.Replace("\\\"", "\"");`.

Comment: Thanks for your help all, but my string does actually contain `\"`. Also, thanks for the downvote LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If string actually contains \":

```
var replaced = myString.Replace(@"\""", @"""")
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I'll accept as correct as soon as I'm able.

Answer (score 2):

You might be confused by a syntaxic trick that C# uses to embed the quote symbol inside of strings. Consider:

```
string abc = "This is a "quote"";  // INVALID SYNTAX, compile will complain
string def = "This is a \"quote\""; // this is ok
```

In this case the \ character is referred to as an escape character and it tells the compiler to ignore the next character and just put it in the string.  The resulting string doesn't actually contain the \ character.  If you do this:

```
string ghi = "This is a \\\"quote\\\""; // this is ok
```

The resulting string will contain a \ and a ", if you want to replace this you can do the following:

```
string newghi = ghi.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

This will replace all \" occurrences with "

Answer (score 0):

In case you're allergic to escape characters (in other words, just for fun, written with no escape characters, e.g. neither `\\` for `\` in a normal string or `""` for `"` in a verbatim string):

```
myString.Replace(@"\"+'"', '"'.ToString())
```

Note that the C# debugger shows `"` as `\"`, so your string might actually just have `"`s. E.g. `string helloWorld = "Hello \"World\"";` shows up in the debugger the same as in the code, `"Hello \"World\""`, not as the string's value, `Hello "World"`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `yourString.Replace("\\\"", "");`